# Prompt user to login as root when running a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, suse

The problem I am getting is, when I enter the command,

```
su - root
```

at the beginning of my shell script file, it prompts the user to enter the password and then does **NOT** continue with the rest of the shell script. I then have to manually locate and run the shell script via terminal. I want the script to make sure that the user logs in as root and then continue with the rest of the shell script.

In other words, I want to run the script as any user but as soon as the script begins to execute,  the user must change to root and then continue on with the rest of the script as root until it is done. Can this be done?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is very easy to accomplish:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$(whoami)" != "root" ] && exec sudo -- "$0" "$@"
```

When the current user isn't root, re-exec the script through `sudo`.

Note that I am using `sudo` here instead of `su`. This is because it allows you to preserve arguments. If you use `su`, your command would have to be `su -c "$0 $@"` which would mangle your arguments if they have spaces or special shell characters.

If your shell is bash, you can avoid the external call to `whoami`:

```
(( EUID != 0 )) && exec sudo -- "$0" "$@"
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in the explanation so it might have been misinterpreted. Here is a more clear explanation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user68857 Your question was clear. This answer does exactly what you want.

Comment: i keep getting this error:   sudo: must be setuid root

Comment: i want to run the script as a regular user via terminal but the script should then switch the user to root until the end of the script

Comment: @Nosscire if you're getting `sudo: must be setuid root`, then something happened to your sudo. To fix it: `chmod u+s $(which sudo)`. And yes, I'm well aware of what you're trying to do, I do the same thing all the time in my scripts.

Comment: hi Patrick, could you take a look at the second question I have posted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132608/changing-user-to-root-when-connected-to-a-linux-server-and-copying-files/. i think you'll be able to give me the response i want. thanks

Comment: Its possible to keep system vars set with EXPORT?

Answer (score 7):

You can check the UID as well:

```
 if [ $(id -u) != 0 ]; then
     echo "You're not root"
     # elevate script privileges
 fi
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call the script itself and check:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ "root" != "$USER" ]; then
  su -c "$0" root
  exit
fi

...
```

Comment: I think it will be more intuitive if the order swapped into `[ "$USER" != "root" ]`. Just another perspective I think.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you want to login, simply add following command

```
sudo su
```

This is working perfectly with my code